# Regarding Scheduling of K8S

Tags: scheduler, kubernetes

Regarding the kubelet status and the policy of kube-scheduler.
The status of kubelet running on my eight workers is ready at the time when i did spawning to create container in RC.

The given message by scheduler is that the RC was well scheduled on across all eight worker nodes. but, the pod status is pending.
i waited as much enough for downloading image but the state didn't changed to running. so, i restarted kubelet service on a worker where having the pending pod. then all pod's pending state had changed running state.

Scheduled well(pod) -> pending(pod) -> restart kubelet -> running(pod)

> why it was resolved after restart kubelet?

The log(kubelet) looks like below.

factory.go:71] Error trying to work out if we can handle /docker-daemon/docker: error inspecting container: No such container: docker

factory.go:71] Error trying to work out if we can handle /docker: error inspecting container: No such container: docker

factory.go:71] Error trying to work out if we can handle /: error inspecting container: unexpected end of JSON input

factory.go:71] Error trying to work out if we can handle /docker-daemon: error inspecting container: No such container: docker-daemon

factory.go:71] Error trying to work out if we can handle /kubelet: error inspecting container: No such container: kubelet

factory.go:71] Error trying to work out if we can handle /kube-proxy: error inspecting container: No such container: kube-proxy

[image]
[image]

Another symptom is with below picture.
The scheduled pod works well. but the condition is false middle in picture
(got from "kubectl describe ~~")

> working well but false...what the false means?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not specific enough for stack overflow, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. In any case, I'd suggest a `kubectl describe pod X` when the pods are in pending. Kubelet logs would also help (they should be in journalctl, or /var/log/kubelet.log depending on your distro).

Comment: updated "kubelet.log" and "kubelet describe" are added